# Edge-case using ng-model in angularjs forms

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, liquid

I have an annoying edge case that I'm dealing with and would love some help.

The situation:

- I'm working on an angular app that is a 'theme' for a donation platform; the donation platform allows us to host theme files (images, stylesheets, javascript, html markup, etc.)
- the platform uses liquid templating to allow use of CSRF tokens as well as to prevent some XSS nastiness.
- the interpolation provider for angular was changed to `// some.expression //` so it wouldn't interfere with the liquid brackets `{{}}`
- so: a 99:1 mix of html/angular and some liquid.
- using angular 1.2.27

The problem:

- the liquid tags also enable us to read data back from the server if a user submits a form and there's an error in it. e.g.: when a user puts their card number in but forgets a field, we can use liquid tags like `{{ user.first_name }}` to safely access that info and populate the value attributes of fields when the form gets reloaded. That way, users don't face a blank form with errors at the top.
- for example:
- `<input ng-blur="validateFName=true" ng-required="true" placeholder="First name" type="text" name="donation[first_name]" ng-model="donation.first_name" value="'{{ donation.first_name }}'">`
- becomes:

  `<input ng-blur="validateFName=true" ng-required="true" placeholder="First name" type="text" name="donation[first_name]" ng-model="donation.first_name" value="John">` the value attr *does* get populated, angular is just ignoring it (and that's the intended use, of course)
- **however**, because of the way that an `ng-model` attribute will work, even though the form elements get their `value` attrs populated, ng-model ignores it and the fields are effectively blank (to the user, anyways)

So: is there any way around this? Essentially, I'm looking for a way to populate the `ng-model`s with the value attribute of their respective field or have `ng-model` acknowledge the `value` attribute. I've looked into ng-bind, -init, -value, and others, but most are for more 'normal' usage of angular. And yes, I know this isn't the best way to utilize angular, but I'm bound in this case by my requirements. Any help would be **greatly** appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try creating a directive that watches the value attribute and updates ng-model on changes.

```
.directive('value', function() {
     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         require: 'ngModel',
         link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
             attr.$observe('value', function(val) {
                 ctrl.$setViewValue(val);
             }
         }
     }
})
```

Comment: that could work; would I need to do anything to have it evaluate on page load?

Comment: (I don't work in angular all that much -- usually work with node and other MV* frameworks, so I'm newish to directives and best use)

Comment: It may not, it's just my best idea for how to do what you are trying to do.  And no, it will run on page load as-is.

Comment: Ok; let me see how the platform handles it

Comment: If you build a plunk around it I can help out.

Comment: I'll throw something together

Comment: Sorry -- wasn't able to put the plunkr together because I got caught doing some other things. However, your solution worked. It allowed the value's to be persisted and synced with/by the ng-models. The only exception was in `selects`, which don't have a value tag and instead get set on an `option` child element. I might have to modify the directive to accomodate that. There were a few minor syntax things in your code, missing a parenthesis at the end from `.directive(....)` (maybe you can fix that in an edit). Aside from that, worked like a charm. -- thanks!

Comment: No problem.  Glad it worked.  Not surprised by syntax issues - I'll fix.

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to populate the data on the model side in your Javascript instead of on the template?

Instead of

```
<input ng-blur="validateFName=true" 
       ng-required="true" 
       placeholder="First name" 
       type="text" 
       name="donation[first_name]" 
       ng-model="donation.first_name" 
       value="'{{ donation.first_name }}'">
```

What if you had in your controller

```
...
$scope.donation.first_name = "'{{ donation.first_name }}'";
...
```